# Align html content(image) of a JEditorPane

Tags: java, image, swing, alignment, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane that is by default 450px X 400px where i put inside an image that is 250px X 250px using HTML in this way :

```
JEditorPane editorPanePreview = new JEditorPane();
String logosrc = MainWindow.class.getResource("/resources/logo.png").toString();
editorPanePreview.setText("<html><img src='" + logosrc + "' ></img></html>");
```

the image is shown correctly but it is by default aligned in the top left corner of the JEditorPane, i want to align it in the bottom right corner of the JEditorPane; Is it possible ?

How can align the content of the JEditorPane in the right bottom corner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this 
http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html
to align content vertically.

You need another view (body or BlockView) to be overridden for HTMLEditorKit though.